# Making line drawn with LineRender clickable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm drawing dynamic lines using LineRender in Unity3d. And now I need to delete this lines by clicking right mouse button on line. But I can't get the click on line. Is there any way to do it or I must use something instead of LineRender?

I tried to add to line EdgeCollider and then catch mouse click like
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0)), Vector2.zero);

```
       if (hit.collider != null)
       {
           Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
       }
```

But this way I can delete only the last drawn line

Here is the way I create lines:

```
void Update(){
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
      {
            if (_line == null)
                CreateLine(material);

            _mousePos = (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, 
                Input.mousePosition.y, -transform.position.z)));
            _line.SetPosition(0, _mousePos);
            _line.SetPosition(1, _mousePos);
        }

        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && _line)
        {
            _mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y,
                -transform.position.z));
        _line.SetPosition(1, _mousePos);
        _line = null;
        }

        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && _line)
        {
            _mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y,
                -transform.position.z));
        _line.SetPosition(1, _mousePos);
        }

    }


    private void CreateLine(Material material)
{
    _line = new GameObject("wall" + walls.Count).AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    _line.material = material;
    _line.gameObject.AddComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
    _line.positionCount = 2;
    _line.startWidth = 0.15f;
    _line.endWidth = 0.15f;
_line.numCapVertices = 50;
    }
```

Comment: I think we need more information. Could you edit your question with the code you use to draw the lines, and the way you add EdgeCollider?

Comment: Have you tried [BakeMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.BakeMesh.html)?

Comment: Maybe I used BakeMesh wrong, but it didn't help me

Comment: problem is that the 2D colliders basically only track collisions from the "side" not frontal ... I would say that the raycast is failing. Did you try to rather use 3D colliders and a 3D raycast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution for destroying independent lines**

So you want to destroy independent lines by a mouse click. Probably the reason you are having the problem of clicking anywhere and destroying the last line, is that you are leaving `EdgeCollider2D` with default data, so all lines have the edge collider in the same points; and somehow your Scene and Camera are in a position where no matter where you click, the `Raycast2D` hits them all, and you delete only one, the first one it hits.

Now the best solution is using the BakeMesh method, but how to implement it correctly.

First, when you create the line instead of `_line.gameObject.AddComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();` add a `MeshCollider`.

Then, after you create the line and let the button up in `else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && _line)` you need to bake the line mesh and attached it to the mesh collider.

```
else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && _line)
    {
        _mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y,
            -transform.position.z));
        _line.SetPosition(1, _mousePos);

        //Bake the mesh
        Mesh lineBakedMesh = new Mesh(); //Create a new Mesh (Empty at the moment)
        _line.BakeMesh(lineBakedMesh, true); //Bake the line mesh to our mesh variable
        _line.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = lineBakedMesh; //Set the baked mesh to the MeshCollider
        _line.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().convex = true; //You need it convex if the mesh have any kind of holes

        _line = null;
    }
```

Also, depending on how your scene is setup you may try making the line not use world space as the default being true, like `_line.useWorldSpace = false;`

To this point, we should have a LineRenderer with a MeshCollider attached where the MeshCollider is the baked mesh of the LineRenderer.

Lastly, how to destroyed them, it's almost the same as you have previously, but instead of Raycast2d, use the normal 3d method ([Physics.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)) because MeshCollider is from 3d physics.

Please read more about:

- [LineRenderer's BakeMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.BakeMesh.html)
- [MeshCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html)
- [MeshCollider's Convex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshCollider-convex.html)
- [MeshCollider's sharedMesh example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshCollider-sharedMesh.html)

**Solution if you want just one line**

The problem is that you creating new independent lines (LineRenderer) each time, so when you want to delete the full line, you are deleting only one of them and not all.

You can continue doing that way but you need to somehow save each independent line in a list and then delete all the line game objects that complete your whole line.

But the best solution is to use LineRenderer to add more points to your line, every time you want a new point yo should increase your LineRendere's `_line.positionCount = line.positionCount + 1;` and then save the position to that point, like `_line.SetPosition(line.positionCount-1, _mousePos);`

Now using [BakeMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.BakeMesh.html) (as @Iggy suggested) would work because you have just one LineRenderer with all points, you just need to use the Mesh you got to a [MeshCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html), and use it like [this example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshCollider-sharedMesh.html).

EDIT: After reading all the comments and code I understand what is what @vviolka wanted, so I add a new solution.

Comment: Maybe my English is too bad, so there's a mistake. I need to delete only one line by clicking it. or did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: Kind of, I mean you are making separete lines for each segment, but is just one big line, right? 
Or you want each line to be independent?

Comment: probably, Yes, each line should be independent. I just need the user to be able to draw several lines, and then delete the line that user click on

Comment: I am not sure if the bakemesh approach would work 100% well: If the line is set to always look at the camera, it would not be correctly warped to match (unless you bake it every frame)? The line changes, your mesh does not. I have had some issues with this before, but not completely sure if this was related to that.

Comment: I understand, so you want them independent. Your problem is that you can only delete the last one? But how? You click any of them and only the last one is destroyed? Or you click at each line but nothing happens until you click the last one that gets destroyed?

Comment: I click any and only the last drown line is destroyed. I click ones more and destroyed the previous and so on

Comment: and what's more I can click anywhere and still delete the last drawn line

Comment: Can you show me the full code of how you destroy the lines?And which object has attached that destroy code.

Comment: Code of destroying:
 `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))`
       `{`

           `RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0)), Vector2.zero);`

          `if (hit.collider != null)`
           `{`
               `Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);`
           `}`
       `}`
and this script is attached to MainCamera

Comment: I think I got the issue, I will update my answer in a minute

Comment: I update the answer. In summary, the problem is that the EdgeCollider2D has the default points when you added it to the line, and when your Raycast2D try to hit, always found them all and gives you one. Using BakedMesh and a MeshCollider you can solve those problems. I hope its clear and it solves the problem:)

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my life, nerves and course work